# UICustom Button scale wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

in Interface Builder I build this view. The 1s are UIButtons

[image]

but on Iphone 6 Simulator, it looks like this

[image]

I set 6 of those Views next to each other in a horizontal scrollable `UIScrollView`.

```
[self.slips setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1842.0f, 322.0f)];

self.slip1 = [[Slip alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip1];

self.slip2 = [[Slip alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(307.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip2];

self.slip3 = [[Slip alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(614.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip3];

self.slip4 = [[Slip alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(921.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip4];

self.slip5 = [[Slip alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1228.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip5];

self.slip6 = [[Slip alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1535.0f, 0.0f, 307.0f, 322.0f)];
[self.slips addSubview:self.slip6];
```

Where`slips` is the `UIScrollView`

The `slip1` is a subclass of `UIView` and set up like this

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
    //
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LottoSlip" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.rootView];
  }
  return self;
}
```

somebody can help why the `UIButtons` are arranged wrongly? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if somebody else has the problem. I fixed it using Images which are exactly the size of the Custom UIButtons, and a version of the image with doubled size and the naming convention.

```
imageName.png
```

and

```
imageName@2x.png
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

please go Hardware And Check Device and Select As Shown Above Image..

[image]

Comment: it have the same problem on different devices settings of the simulator.

Comment: please Check your View In Nib/Parametrically

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but where can I find the list you were posting, I didnt check this yet. I couldnt find it in the Project's plist. I also don´t know where to find Nib/Parametrically please forgive my un-knowledge.